# Why does multiprocessing serialisation with pickling depend on scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization, multiprocessing, pickle

I am trying to understand how concurrency works in generall and, in this case, how does it work specifically in Python.

I have been using the `inputs` library for a while now and always had to "cheat" when spawning processes using it - execute the script with `subprocess.Popen`. Today I have, without much thought, placed a single line of code in a different place and managed to successfully spawn a `Process` targetting a function. But I don't understand why does it work...

The following code exposes two simple classes, one holds a reference to `controller` in *self* and the other one doesn't (and uses the global reference declared in the module):

```py
import inputs
import multiprocessing
import time

controller = inputs.devices.gamepads[0]


class TestBroken:

    def __init__(self):
        self.controller = controller

    def read(self):
        while True:
            ev = self.controller.read()[0]
            print(ev.code, ev.state)


class TestWorking:

    def read(self):
        while True:
            ev = controller.read()[0]
            print(ev.code, ev.state)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = TestWorking()
    # Uncomment the line below to get the errors
    #t = TestBroken()
    multiprocessing.Process(target=t.read).start()
    while True:
        print("I'm alive!")
        time.sleep(1)
```

The error after uncommenting `#t = TestBroken()` is as follows:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Coding/...", line 31, in <module>
    multiprocessing.Process(target=t.read).start()
  File "C:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 326, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'CDLL.__init__.<locals>._FuncPtr'
```

I can't quite understand how storing a reference to an object is making `pickle` go bonkers while storing the same reference on module level is allowed. I kindly request your assistance to uncover the mysteries behind this issue.

Answer (score 0):

While one starts multiprocessing, the global variables of the parent process is copied to as many child process created. Hence any change in the parent process shall not reflect on the copies of the child processes. The part of code in class TestBroken has a constructor which allocate the class variable to the global variable and later try to read it. While the class TestWorking just created a local variable ev to read the controller ( which is in global scope ).

Comment: That doesn't at all describe the pickling issues nor why this case would work. You can easily replace the global controller instance with some custom class instead of the `inputs` one, and pickle it successfully. Both `TestBroker` and `TestWorking` would work just fine. Furthermore, the parent process doesn't even get to change anything because it fails to create due to the pickling error as described above.